# Laravel Routing Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model named `PriceList` and when I use the `::resource` function of the Routing, it only works if I pass `price/lists` as the first parameter.

For example, if I do the following:

```
Route::resource('pricelists', 'PriceListsController');
```

Then inside my controller, I do the following:

```
use App\PriceList;

class PriceListsController
{
    public function show(PriceList $list)
    {
        dd($list);
    }
}
```

If I visit the url: `/pricelists/1`, it's giving me an empty instance of `PriceList`:

```
PriceList {#802 ▼
  #appends: array:4 [▶]
  #hidden: array:4 [▶]
  #with: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

However, if I change the resource to:

```
Route::resource('price/lists', 'PriceListsController');
```

And visit the url: `/price/lists/1`, I then get the right instance of `PriceList`:

```
PriceList {#820 ▼
  #appends: array:4 [▶]
  #hidden: array:4 [▶]
  #with: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

How can I change it from `price/lists` to `pricelists`?

### Update

I've tried using `Route::model` function in my `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::model('pricelists', App\PriceList::class);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks I looked at the list of routes and found the problem. I was using `pricelists` in the `::model` function instead of `pricelist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at `php artisan route:list`, and found the following route:

```
|GET|HEAD| api/pricelists/{pricelist}|pricelists.show|App\Http\Controllers\PriceListsController@show|web,auth|
```

So I've changed my `RouteServiceProdiver` to:

```
Route::model('pricelist', PriceList::class);
```